# Inscription to the right of textbox

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, css-position

How can I display the inscription with CSS to do it cross-browser, and did not depend on the screen resolution?

I am trying do it as

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.User) 
<p class="myclass">text text text</p>

myclass {
margin-left:30%; 
position:absolute; 
top:200px;
}
```

Comment: why not float the text box and inscription?

Comment: Do you mean `<label>` ?

Comment: Thanks, guys! `<label>` approached me.